# Create API key in CoinBase

Tags: cryptocurrency, coinbase-api

I want to develop an application that allow users to buy and sell cryptocurrency. While doing my research I found out that CoinBase provide such APIs. So, I started following the document https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#introduction I signed up at https://developers.coinbase.com/ and tried to create the API Key. It sends an otp on my registered mobile number, I entered the otp and then few details but when I click on Create API Key, it again sends an otp and this continues in a loop.

Can anyone here, help me how I can create an API Key in coin base to test the APIs?

Also, while going through the document, I can see that there are APIs to show, update or delete account or user but I can't find any API to create an account or user. May I know, how an account or user is created using coinbase API?

A fast response will be appreciated.